# Caching MessageSender and MessageReceiver

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

According to MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx) we should cache the objects used to communicate with Service Bus. It dosen't however explain it in more details. 
To be more specific I create the `MessagingFactory` for given connection string and cache it as long as possible. I use the factory to create the `MessageReciever` and `MessageSender` instances for different queues and topics. Now my question is: Should I also cache them? 
I do not call the `Close` on them.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, when we say *cache* here, what we mean is *keep a reference to the object*, not *store it in a cache [like Redis]*. The guidance from Microsoft is just pointing out that establishing a connection to Service Bus is an expensive operation compared to just sending/receiving messages, and there's no benefit to tearing down the connection and reestablishing it on every send/receive.

When I write code using these objects, I usually create a static property on a class and keep it in there, so the objects last for the lifetime of the app domain. In an ASP.NET application, if you don't like the static class approach, you could keep the Service Bus objects in the [HttpContext.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, for example, `Application["ServiceBusReceiver"] = myServiceBusReceiver;` and then you just keep pulling it out when you need it.

(And, yes, there are other ways to do "global" objects in ASP.NET... not looking to wade into that topic here. :-) )

This is (sort-of) the same idea as SQL connection pooling... once the connections are established, they're kept around and reused. Ultimately, it's not a functional difference, it's just a performance optimization that reduces the number of calls over the network.

Hope that helps,

Scott

Comment: There are very few threadsafe calls in the .NET servicebus SDK so beware. The real problem is that the Servicebus team needs to properly address usage in a stateless environment.

Comment: This answer does not satisfy this key part of the question: what is the lifecycle of the objects under a `MessagingFactory` (MessageReceiver/MessageSender)? Does closing a MessageReceiver affect the underlying connection? Does failing to close it create any sort of a leak?